# Imagemagick create image and place image inside with max size

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have trimmed .pngs and need them placed on a canvas (3000x3000 px) **BUT** with a max size.

```
convert -size 3000x30000 xc:transparent test.png -gravity south -composite -size 2200x2200 result.png
```

The code I have now  works, but the sizing of the image is off. My canvas is 3000x3000px as intended, but the image placed on the canvas doesn't have the correct size. It should have a max width/height of 2200px and if possible be scaled up, if they are to small in **height**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This ImageMagick command will resize the input image to 2200 pixels on the longer side while maintaining its aspect, then create a 3000x3000 transparent canvas, then swap the input image and the canvas, and finish by compositing the resized input image onto the transparent canvas...

```
convert input.png -resize 2200x2200 \
   -size 3000x3000 xc:none +swap -gravity south -composite result.png
```

For Windows change that continued line backslash "\" to a caret "^". For ImageMagick v7 use "magick" instead of "convert".

Answer (score 1):

Unix syntax:

```
convert -size 3000x30000 xc:transparent \( test.png -resize 2200x2200 \) -gravity south -composite result.png
```

Windows syntax:

```
convert -size 3000x30000 xc:transparent ( test.png -resize 2200x2200 ) -gravity south -composite result.png
```

Comment: With this syntax I get this error on mac os x mojave:  

`convert -size 1400x1400 xc:transparent \(./trimmed/p-001.png -resize 1000x1000\) -gravity south -composite ./composed/output.png`  
`convert: unable to open image '(./trimmed/p-001.png': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3497.`  
`convert: image sequence is required '-composite' @ error/mogrify.c/MogrifyImageList/7986.`  
`convert: no images defined './composed/output.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3273.`  

i tried with the full path too, but got the same error

Comment: That error appears to come from not escaping your parentheses with backslashes like \\(...\\).

Comment: You need spaces both sides of escaped parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use -extent?

```
convert input.jpg -resize 2200x2200 -background none -gravity south -extent 3000x3000 result.png
```